# Netflix Authorization Request

Tags: post, request, authorization, netflix

I need to make a POST request to authorize on Netflix. I tried to find something similar in the network tab in chrome developer tools, but I can't find anything, it's like the request didn't exist. Please advise me where I can find it. Thanks in advance

As I wrote above, I tried to find the POST request that sends the data (email and password) to the server using the developer tools, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.